# Reading SVG fragment from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, svg

I have generated a JSON file that contains a long array of 'icon' objects, each of which consists of a name and a path:

```
[
...
{
    "name": "add",
    "path": "<svg><path d=\"M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z\"><\/path><\/svg>,<path d=\"M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z\">"
},
...
]
```

The JSON file validates but when I try to create an index of the icons using:

```
const allIcons = parsedIcons.map((icon) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="24" width="24">
        {icon.path}
      </svg>
      <p>{icon.name}</p>
    </li>
  )
})
```

and then dropping allIcons into an unordered list but for each icon, {icon.path} comes through as a string - '<' is converted to `&lt;`, etc. and the SVG doesn't render. I've tried JSON.stringify and then JSON.parse and all permutations of those 2 but without any success.

It seems like there is some fundamental concept I am just missing and I've been butting my head against it all day! Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to dynamically render HTML and React doesn't know how to do that by default. This is actually a *good* thing in that it can prevent malicious code from being inadvertently injected into your application (a la cross-site scripting).

That being said, React understands this limitation and provides an escape hatch with the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) prop.

Here's an example of how you might use it with your code:

```js
  const allIcons = parsedIcons.map((icon, idx) => (
    <li key={idx}>
      <svg
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        height="24"
        width="24"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: icon.path }}
      ></svg>
      <p>{icon.name}</p>
    </li>
  ));
```

And, here's a working example of your code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-river-m7wmg?file=/src/App.js:548-807).

As an additional reminder, the prop is named *dangerously*SetInnerHTML because doing this can expose your application to cross-site scripting attacks. As such, I would strongly encourage you to consider using a sanitization library such as [react-sanitized-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sanitized-html).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Only store the path decriptor in your JSON.

```
[
...
{
    "name": "add",
    "path": "M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"
},
...
]
```

And change your component to:

```
const allIcons = parsedIcons.map((icon) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="24" width="24">
        <path d="{icon.path}"/>
      </svg>
      <p>{icon.name}</p>
    </li>
  )
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I had taken this approach to begin with and unfortunately there is information in the path tag itself that varies by icon. Additionally, some of the icons have multiple paths so it wasn't completely working to just use the path information.

Comment: You caould always turen `path` into an array.  In many cases you should be able to merge the paths into one path definition.